# Finding the basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for these subspaces:

U1 =

{(x1, x2, x3, x4) ∈ R
4
| x1 + 2x2 + 3x3 = 0}

U2 =

{(x1, x2, x3, x4) ∈ R
4
| x1 + x2 + x3 − x4 = x1 − 2x2 + x4 = 0}

My attempt:

for U1; I created a vector in which one variable, different in each vector, is zero and another is 1 and got three vectors: (3,0,-1,1), (0,3,-2,1), (2,1,0,1)

Same approach to U2 got me 4 vectors, one of which was dependent, basis is:

(1,0,0,-1), (2,1,-3,0), (1,2,0,3)

I'd appreciate corrections or if there is a more technical way to approach this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is obvious that $x_1 = -2 x_2 - 3 x_3$. So, the set becomes
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   U_1 &= \{(-2 x_2 - 3 x_3, \, x_2, \, x_3, \, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4\} \\ &= \{ x_2 \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + x_3 \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + x_4 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \mid x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \mathbb{R}\}
   \end{align*}
   $$
   So $\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $ \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ are natural candidates for a basis.
2. Obtain that $x_3 = x_2 - 2 x_1$ and $x_4 = 2 x_2 - x_1$. So, in the same manner:
   \begin{align*}
   U_2 &= \{(x_1, \, x_2, \, x_2 - 2 x_1, \, 2 x_2 - x_1) \in \mathbb{R}^4\} \\ &= \{ x_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} + x_2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \mid x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}
   \end{align*}

Comment: For U2, the vector (1,0,0,-1) solves the equations and isn't covered by the span of (1,0,-2,-1) and (0,1,1,2), or am I missing something?

Comment: $(1,\, 0, \, 0, \, -1)$ isn't a solution to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - x_4 = 0$ and $x_1 - 2 x_2 + x_4 = 0$.